# Prestashop edits not updating

Tags: caching, prestashop

I have a prestashop page, and im trying to change few images in a catalog article, but somehow the page changes are not showing - it shows as no changes are done. Anyone know what can the problem be - I've disabled and cleared cache. Prestashop version is 1.4.7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **Advanced Parameters  > Performance**

And in Smarty Select the following :

**Template cache > Recompile templates if the files have been updated**

**Cache > Yes**

**Debug console > Do not open console**

Let me know if this helps plus remember to clear the browser cache as well.

Comment: For me it helped to turn off the Cache button that is on the very bottom of Advanced Parameters -> Performance page.